# How to using php to encrypt data on the server and decrypt data on client using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, encryption

I am building a simple training website using php. I want to share my training material without fear of copyright infringement. I want to send encrypted documents from the server and decrypt them (on the user's machine using javascript - which means he can peek into it) and displays it. This way, the user doesn't simply get the document but needs to decrypt it.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: if they have a decrypted copy then what was the point?

Comment: @dagon The file is for view only and cannot be copied. using javascript to disable copy.

Comment: You can safely do that, especially if your decryption algorithm is in JavaScript. In addition, by disabling copy functionality with JavaScript you essentially have blocked the entire world from being able to steal it.

Comment: if you can view it you can copy it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're afraid that the user will "steal" your content by copying or printing it, consider sending the content in secure PDF files. http://www.primopdf.com/help/tip_secure_pdf.aspx

You can disable features such as printing and copy-pasting in PDF files.
You can also have the PDF files auto expire after few days or under password protection.

Comment: if it's on my screen i can copy it. if need be OCR the image.

Comment: yeah.  securing documents is usually just making it harder to copy, not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide your data on a public site with no user management any encryption and decryption in javascript is senseless, because everybody could decrypt this on his own. What helps might be a user management.